# Visual Basic Change specific line in XML

Tags: xml, visual-studio

I am happy to admit i am very new to VS. I have been slowly learning but i am stuck on two things to complete my project.

I would like to use a button to write/change part of a line in an XML from true to false

Specific line from XML below:

```
<FactorChange active="true" directory="C:/Temp"/>
```

I would also like to use a `FolderBrowserDialog` to be able to select a location and apply the path to a button, that when pressed writes that information(the path) to the xml (after directory) and changes (active) to true if it says false.

e.g User selects button, Page opens and they select "directory button", this then opens the `FolderBrowserDialog` and they select the location. They now type a name for the button and press save. This button now acts as above.

When finished with button user can select button using a `ToolStripMenuItem` and select "Clear Button" and it is left blank ready to be used again. 
e.g File > Clear Button > "Button Name"

I have the structure in place and the menu's but need help with the functionality. Happy to upload any files if needed :-)

I hope this makes sense. I have searched and watch tutorials for hours but i am lost on the best way to search for my answer. I am happy for any kind of direction

Thankyou for any help or links to the write subject information that can be given.

AG

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question is too broad to be suitable as an SO question, since it contains many questions in one (How do I handle a button click? How do I show a FolderBrowserDialog? How do I change a line in an XML file?). Please ask *one specific question* per SO question. Actually, once you have broken down your problem into smaller pieces, you might find that many of those small pieces already have an answer here on SO. :-)

Comment: I understand but i have broken them down and don't know how to reference them to existing questions asked or i would. Thanks anyway i guess